# Getting CastClassException in Spark 2: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, struct, hive

Getting CastClassException in Spark 2 when dealing with table having complex datatype columns like Array and Array

The actions I tried is simple one: count

```
df=spark.sql("select * from <tablename>")
df.count
```

but getting below Error when running the spark application

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 5, sandbox.hortonworks.com, executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableStringObjectInspector.getPrimitiveWritableObject(WritableStringObjectInspector.java:41)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveInspectors$$anonfun$unwrapperFor$23.apply(HiveInspectors.scala:529)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(TableReader.scala:419)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(TableReader.scala:419)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$$anonfun$fillObject$2.apply(TableReader.scala:435)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$$anonfun$fillObject$2.apply(TableReader.scala:426)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
```

The weird thing is, the same action of dataframe in `spark-shell` is working fine

Table has below complex columns :

```
|-- sku_product: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- sku_id: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- qty: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- price: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- display_name: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- sku_displ_clr_desc: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- sku_sz_desc: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- parent_product_id: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- delivery_mthd: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- pick_up_store_id: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- delivery: string (nullable = true)
|-- hitid_low: string (nullable = true)
|-- evar7: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|-- hitid_high: string (nullable = true)
|-- evar60: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

let me know if any further information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was using spark 2.1 with parquet files. 
I discovered that one of the parquet files had a different schema than the others. So when I tried to read all, I got cast error. 
In order to resolve it, I just checked file by file.

Comment: but the table is stored as an orc, if you know something regarding it please share.

Comment: I am not familiar with ORC, Are you using save as table or save files API ? since if you are using save as table you should be protected by spark api